# Jquery script seem to stop working after css media query kicks in

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I have got some issues here.

If i run the script, when the window width is above 800px, the menu loads. I then resize the window below 800px, the menu is swapped out with a button. But the button doesn't work. And if i resize the window above 800px, the menu appears again as it should.

If i run the script, when the window width is below 800px, the button works. But then i resize the window above 800px, the menu doesn't appear (unless i left it open before resizing), which it should. And the button still works if i resize the window below 800px again.

The jQuery part is only supposed to work when the window width is below 800px.

I'm not sure why this shouldn't work?

http://jsfiddle.net/y35axgpg/7/

---

## Update

Thanks for the help, apparently i'm too tired today, and should not be working at this hour. What you told me i already knew back in my mind, but needed a kick in the right direction.

This is what i came up with: https://jsfiddle.net/y35axgpg/15/

---

jQuery

```
if ($("#menu_button").css("display") == "inline-block") {

  $("#menu_button").click(function() {
    $("#main_menu").toggle("slide");
  });

}
```

CSS

```
#main_menu {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
}

#menu_button {
        display: none;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  #main_menu {
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
  }

    #menu_button {
        display: inline-block;
    }

}
```

Comment: Of course it works only if screen size is less than 800px because of your if check

Comment: Declare your `.click()` function outside of the `if` condition, then `.trigger('click')` the `.click()` function within the `if` condition. **E.g:** https://jsfiddle.net/y35axgpg/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.click()` event is only being bound when the condition evaluates to `true` - which can only happen on page load *IF* the condition is already *true* - like when the screen size is below `800px`.

Declare your `.click()` function outside of the `if` condition, so that it is always bound to that button. Then `.trigger('click')` the `.click()` function within the `if` condition.

**E.g:** https://jsfiddle.net/y35axgpg/10/

```js
$("#menu_button").click(function() {
  $("#main_menu").toggle();
});

if ($("#menu_button").css("display") == "inline-block") {

  $("#menu_button").trigger('click')

}
```

```css
#main_menu {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
}

#menu_button {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #main_menu {
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #menu_button {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="menu_button">Menu</button>
<div id="main_menu">[link] | [link] | [link] | [link] | [link]</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "when the script runs". The script only runs when the page is loaded, not when the page is resized. So in your case if you load the page larger than 800 px, the event listener will not be bound to the button.

You can to fix this, by removing the if statement, because I see no use in that, this way the event listener will always be bound to the button.